# How to correctly repeat nested transitions in d3?

Tags: d3.js, transition

Currently, the code below moves the squares in an undulating fashion, but I want to change it so there is a single traveling wave (like they do in the stadiums). I guess what I have to do is figure out how to add a delay to the repeat loop so the first square goes down and stays down until the last square starts to go up.

[image]

Here's my code and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5zm18hn/):

```
var margin = {top: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40, right: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.bottom - margin.top;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var n = 20,
    rect_width = 20,
    padding = 1, 
    speed = 1000,
    item_delay = 40;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(n))
    .rangePoints([0, n * (rect_width + padding)]);

var rects = svg.selectAll(".rect")
    .data(x.domain())
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){ return x(i); })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", rect_width)
    .attr("width", rect_width)
    .attr("class", "rect")
  .transition() 
    .duration(speed)
    .delay(function(d,i){ return i * 120; })
    .each(start_repeat);

function start_repeat(){
    var rect = d3.select(this);
    (function repeat(){
        rect = rect.transition()
            .attr("y", 0)
          .transition()
            .attr("y", 100)
            .each("end", repeat);    
    })()
}
```

I think my problem is that I don't really understand what's going on inside the `repeat` function.

**UPDATE**

I figured out a simple to loop the transition, but it requires that I manually calculate the loop duration and I'd like to avoid this (see snippet for a live version).

```
speed = 500;
var loop_duration = 2000;
(function loop(){
rects.transition()
    .delay(function(d,i){ return i * item_delay; })
    .duration(speed)
    .attr("y", 100) // down
  .transition()
    .attr("y", 0)
setTimeout(loop, loop_duration)
})()
```

```js
var margin = {top: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40, right: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.bottom - margin.top;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var n = 20,
    rect_width = 20,
    padding = 1, 
    speed = 500,
    item_delay = 100;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(n))
    .rangePoints([0, n * (rect_width + padding)]);

var rects = svg.selectAll(".rect")
    .data(x.domain())
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){ return x(i); })
    .attr("height", rect_width)
    .attr("width", rect_width)
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .attr("y", 0); // up - very important, if you don't set this, there is no interpolation

var loop_duration = 2000;
(function loop(){
    rects.transition()
        .delay(function(d,i){ return i * item_delay; })
        .duration(speed)
        .attr("y", 100) // down
      .transition()
        .attr("y", 0)
    setTimeout(loop, loop_duration)
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I've tried deparsing the `start_repeat` function to understand what's going on, but I still don't get it. For example, **what is the difference between `old_rect` and `rect`**?

```
function start_repeat() {
  var rect = d3.select(this);
  (function repeat() {
    var move_down_t0 = rect.transition() // chain the down-transition on the same selection
        .attr("y", 100);

     var move_up_t1 = move_down_t0.transition()
        .attr("y", 0)

     old_rect = rect;
     rect = move_up_t1.each("end", repeat);
  })();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused myself, but I tried setting the duration and delays to be equal, such that the transition lasts as long as the values are set down.

Try this:

```
var rects = svg.selectAll(".rect")
    .data(x.domain())
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){ return x(i); })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", rect_width)
    .attr("width", rect_width)
    .attr("class", "rect")
  .transition() 
    .duration(speed)
    .delay(function(d,i){ return i * (speed/(n*2)); })
    .each(start_repeat);
```

Comment: Also, the documentation in this tutorial may be helpful: http://alignedleft.com/projects/2014/easy-as-pi/

Comment: Thanks for the link. That seems worth digging into. Any ideas on how to add a pause after each wave?

Comment: Take a look at the end of that link. I would just set the duration longer than the delay. Alternatively, perhaps set a delay in the .each function.

Comment: what did you settle upon?

Comment: I've updated the question adding a snippet that shows the approximate behavior that I'm after. I would still like a version that used nested transitions instead of `setTimeout` because I don't want to have to calculate the duration manually. Any ideas? Also, I'd like to understand better what the `start_repeat` function is doing.

Comment: In my example, see how I calculate the duration with n. That may help. What confuses you in start-repeat? it is a callback function on each element you append to the svg.

Comment: For example, I don't understand why `rect` has to be reassigned. What is the difference between `old_rect` and `rect`? I appreciate your solution, but it doesn't really look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nachocab/sLyLjn7b/1/)

Comment: @nachocab What is wrong with my solution? I prepared one more like your fiddle without setTimeout [http://jsfiddle.net/k5zm18hn/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/k5zm18hn/4/)

Comment: @slotomo you're still calculating the duration manually in `pausing_delay`. I was trying to avoid this and just be it a by-product of the chained transitions.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/k5zm18hn/2/

```
function repeat(){
    if(d3.select(this).attr("y")==0){
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .delay(pausing_delay)
            .duration(speed)
            .attr("y", 100)
            .each("end", repeat);
    }
    else{
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .attr("y", 0)
            .duration(speed)
            .each("end", repeat);
    }
}
```

Change pausing_delay variable for optimal results.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/k5zm18hn/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/k5zm18hn/3/) - another example when pausing_delay is 1600ms